# Set input text inside iframe and submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, iframe

I'm trying to glue together two web services by passing a value from one to the other, unfortunately there's no API or clear way of hacking up the search query so I need to set the value of a input inside an iframe.

Here's the markup for the horrible iframe.

```
<form id="searchForm" method="post" action="/search/initialSearch">         
  <fieldset class="searchFields">
    <input type="text" name="searchTerm" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" value="Find stops"/>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

I need to set the searchTerm text and then submit the form.

**Note: This is going over mobile, so I would prefer a really lightweight solution**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Isn't it as simple as:

```
myframe.document.getElementById("searchForm").searchTerm.value = 'hello';
myframe.document.getElementById("searchForm").submit();
```

Make sure your script runs AFTER the `iframe` is loaded. Your `iframe` tag has an `onload` event that you can use to determine when the page within the frame is loaded.

```
<iframe src="formPage.html" onload="loaded()" name="myframe" />
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I make sure that the frame is loaded? is there some kind of event that is triggered?

Comment: You can add a function reference to the iframe's onload attribute: <iframe onload="imLoaded()" ... />

Comment: You'll have issues if you're doing stuff cross-domains, that's one thing to watch out for. Otherwise, that's definitely a workable solution.

Comment: Absolutely right, Stobor. I went ahead and updated the code - I instinctively used google as my example - shouldn't have :)

Comment: Thanks for the updated code sample, very clean. I  actually doing cross domain stuff, so it looks like I need a little proxy

Comment: Yeah; you'll need a proxy if you're going cross-domain.

Comment: I spent hours on this ... firefox didn't give me such a problem. Instad chrome did ...

Answer (score 8):

just be aware that if your iframe's source is not coming from your server, it is impossible to access its contents with javascript from the page that contains the iframe. If you have access to the contents of the iframe that is coming from another server, then you can access all of the data from the parent page with:

```
window.top
```

If you do not have access to the iframe's page, then there is nothing you can do.

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to access the web service from your server code?

If so, I'd sack off the iframe and create a proxy on your server. This would keep your HTML clean and lightweight for your intended audience.

Comment: That seems like a good idea, I'm using php got any code or links for a simple proxy?

Comment: Sorry Tom I'm an ASP.NET man myself. If I come across any examples I'll post them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to set the value of input in an extern loaded iFrame (No proxy):

```
const iFrameEl = document.getElementById('form-iframe');
  const innerDoc = iFrameEl.contentDocument || 
    iFrameEl.contentWindow.document; 
            
    const inputEl = innerDoc.getElementById('email-input');

    inputEl.value = 'test@email.com';
```

Found [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/656521/Get-or-Set-value-to-Controls-inside-iFrame-from-Pa)

Don't know how to emit submit. But I guess the use of `contentDocument` might work here as well.

Comment: Scroll down the linked article and the 'Important Note' reads: This technique will work, if the Parent Page and iFrame both are in the Same Domain. If any of them is in a Different Domain, then we have to follow Window Message Passing technique ....