# Laravel Post return 405 when input parameter contains <iframe></iframe> tag

Tags: laravel

today i'm facing a very strange issue with laravel. it's a simple app, which have a input field. when user hit the submit the button, it's post the form data and store it to the database.
Now, when i input anything except `<iframe></iframe>` tag on the input field, it's working fine. but when i put it, it's return me to the   405 bad request page.

it's look like laravel don't allow to post a string which contains `<iframe>` tag on it.

Comment: Please share part your code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide detailed information about your problem. Similar to your question asked [Set input text inside iframe and submit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1073866/4721265). Maybe you can do this using JavaScript:

```
myframe.document.getElementById("searchForm").searchTerm.value = 'hello';
myframe.document.getElementById("searchForm").submit();
```

and in html (or blade):

```
<iframe src="formPage.html" onload="loaded()" name="myframe" />
```

Comment: Not actually. i'm not putting my form into a iframe. 
the issue is when i pass a string which contains <iframe> tag on it, is not accepted by the laravel post method. 

eg: 
you have form with a input field . when you enter <iframe> on the input field and submit the form, laravel return the error. but when you enter any other html tag or any text, it's working fine.

Comment: @Jabed Bhuiyan. Please edit your question. Put your code and errors in question because your question is vague without source code.